# I want to receive data from a module by using Python Programming and using LAN wire

Tags: python, networking

i'am using this code to connect with a module of ip address 20.20.20.170 but i'm not able to do. I've used all socket programming codes but no one is working. Remember i have to only receive data. Can any one help me to resolve this problem

code is here...

```
import socket

TCP_IP='20.20.20.170'
TCP_PORT=20108
buffer_size=1024
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
output=s.recv(1024)
print(output)
s.close()
print("received data:",data)
```

Comment: can you be more specific by "not working" ? is there any error message ? does the program hang ? what if you simply `nc 20.20.20.170 20108` ? do you get something ? if not, that could be a firewall instead of a python issue.

Comment: ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. I'm getting this type of error.

Comment: is a server running on port `20108` ? is a firewall running ?

Comment: i have no idea about firewall . how i can fix it?

Comment: first things first, is a server running on port `20108` ? `netstat -an` can help here